# How to translate "march wearing in one uniform: leadership"

Tags: translation

> Looking back at my two weeks at NYMA, I've learned many valuable lessons, but the most important lesson I will remember is that people from different background all over the world, can create unforgettable experiences together when they march wearing one uniform: leadership.

上面这个句子的最后一部分该怎么翻译呢？直翻感觉很別扭。

Comment: The last sentence reads unnaturally - “in” does not need to be there.

Comment: That's my bad, there wasn't an "in" there.

Answer (score 2):

I may have understood the text wrong, but here is my trial

> 回顾我在 NYMA 训练的两周时，我感觉自学到了许多宝贵的知识。这其中最重要的，就是当这世界上来自不同文化、不同背景的人们都为了一个目标训练（行军）时，能创造出这么多令人难忘的回忆瞬间。而这个目标，就是领导能力。

Comment: I like your translation better, but does it alter the original meaning of the speaker?

Comment: @shenkwen I am not sure, could you please explain more about the text you quoted?

Answer (score 1):

回顾我在NYMA的两周，我收获了许多宝贵经验，其中至为重要一条，就是来自世界各地背景殊异的人们，也能在拼搏于统一领导之下时，共同创造难忘经历。

If we must emphasize leadership, it is unnatural if we put it straight forward because it is awkward to put when clause at the end of the sentence. So my best try:

回顾我在NYMA的两周，我收获了许多宝贵经验，其中至为重要一条，就是来自世界各地背景殊异的人们，也有共同创造难忘经历的可能，即当他们拼搏于统一领导之下时得以实现。

More information needed to interpret the figurative expression: march wearing in one uniform: leadership.